# How model can directly communicate with view in MVC architecture?

Tags: android, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I have seen some of the demos for MVC architecture in Android. First of all, for android mvc is there or not ? In some tutorials it is mentioned that view directly communicates with model. how exactly it works in android It is confusion.

Comment: Please link to the demos and tutorials you are referencing, so we can see them too. Also, have you searched SO? What did you find here? This seems like potentially a common question.

Comment: @jaco0646 for instance this demo, https://medium.com/cr8resume/make-you-hand-dirty-with-mvp-model-view-presenter-eab5b5c16e42

Comment: In short, it should work like this: The controller only updates the model, e.g. it sends data to the model layer (_create_, _update_ & _delete_ ops). The view only queries the model for data (_read_ operation) and presents it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a view model.
see https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: This is mvvm , the question is about mvc